# why is this logic proof wrong?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am doing the exercises in the book: 'Introduction to logic' (Harry Gensler, 2010).
My solution for exercise 7.3a nº2 is not correct. Why?
The argument is valid, but from the book's solution, I could not have derived line 6.

[my proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97yQ1.jpg)

[book proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R60uZ.png)

Comment: Maybe the issue is: what are the rules that allow you to derive a contradiction?

Comment: An alternative proof may be: assume $C$ and derive from it $(A \land B \to C)$. With it derive $(D \to E)$ and using 2nd premise derive $E$. Now, using CP, discharge assumption $C$ to conclude with $C \to E$.

Comment: I believe your proof is also valid, the bit where you depart basically just boils down to Modus Tollens.

Comment: The issue in your proof is: how you derive $\lnot (A \land B \to C)$ **without** using a truth table?

Comment: If you are allowed to use [Modus Tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens#Formal_notation), from assumption $\lnot (C \to E)$ you have $\lnot E$. With $D$ you get $(D \land \lnot E)$ that is $\lnot (D \to E)$. Now use MT with 1 to get $\lnot (A \land B \to C)$

Comment: Your book is using a really weird logic, which is very suspicious.

Comment: @StephenDonovan,  I believe this is it. perhaps the author considers the extra assumption of line 6 just to show that this was possible. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA . this is what I did using Modus tollens. So my derivation of line 6 is correct. This reinforces the idea that the author just used too many assumptions. The proof could be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just lacking a bit of detail. Filling the gaps using a simplified form natural deduction, we have:

(Screen shot from my proof checker)

[image]
[image]

**BONUS ANSWER**

Makes use of the principle: $P \implies [Q \implies P]$ on line 6 (not sure what the Latin name is)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @DanChristenses. I am starting the study of logic. I found the DC Proof system very interesting.